# Java searching for a right pattern

Tags: design-patterns

There is the next task I have :

Create an application that represents a Taxi station with 10 taxies.
Taxi station enables:

- Order taxi
- Cancel taxi
- Be aware when taxi gets available

A person that orders a taxi may be a regular customer or a VIP customer.

If a VIP orders a taxi, he/she should be first in line regardless of the time he requested the service.

Where no taxi is available, a person should be kept on the waiting list.

When a taxi becomes available, a person according to priority gets the free taxi.

Print to console every reservation accepted/queued.

Execute:

1. Create a taxi station with 10 taxis
2. Order a taxi for 9 regular persons
3. Order a taxi for 1 VIP person
4. Order taxi for 2 regular person
5. Order a taxi for 1 VIP person
6. 1 Taxi is back in the station
7. Order a taxi for 1 VIP person
8. the Second taxi is back at the station
9. Third taxi is back at the station

So, the question is:
Which design pattern fits the most to this task?
How would you solve this case? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observer pattern. And 2 queues (vip / not vip).